# Add section to navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

i have the below code :

activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;

        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

and for the section i have the below xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navmenusection_label"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BBB"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:text="Section"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So how can i add the section in the navigation drawer. ?
i have change the NavDrawerListAdapter.java file :

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            /*
             * convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_section,
             * parent, false);
             */
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()) {
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        } else {
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

`convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_section,
                    parent, false);`

i have put this in `getView()` but i am getting the error .

Logcat :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.novumlogic.euphoria, PID: 26846
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.novumlogic.euphoria.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter.getView(NavDrawerListAdapter.java:59)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2338)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1812)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1631)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2149)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2023)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how can i add the section ?

Comment: Please include the source of your adapter as well. That is pretty much the only relevant class for setting up the sectioned list. Also, the actual error message or stack trace would help.

Comment: What error do you get???

Comment: @Ridcully added logcat

Answer (score 0):

first remove any changes that you have done which causes a null pointer exception then go to `drwer_list_item.xml` and add text view for your section part, then go to `NavDrawerItem.class` and add:

```
private String section;
```

change your constructor to this:

```
public NavDrawerItem(String title, int icon,String section){
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.section= section;
}
```

you also have to add getters and setters for your private section instanse:

```
public String getSection(){
    return this.section;
}

public void setSection(String section){
    this.section = section;
}
```

then go to `navDrewerListAdapter.class` and add this:

```
TextView txtSection = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.section);
```

last thing you have to do is to change your `navDrawerItems.add` from this:

```
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[index], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(index, -1)));
```

to this:

```
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[index], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(index, -1),"String Section"));
```

hope this will help.

Comment: no it is not working. it is not showing section name

Comment: i think you are missing any steps in `navDrewerListAdapter.class` ?